# How to customize email template in crm 2016 by code

Tags: email, templates, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using CRM 2016, and trying to customize email template by adding a dynamic data. I know that CRM allows to use only specific vanilla entities, but when I explorer an old code I found an option to use {0}, {1} etc' for injecting data from non vanilla entities (by code) - unfortunately that code cannot be tested...
Have someone heard or know about that way? is it possible? what to google for?

Comment: What I feel is they kept markers like {0} and then in some email pre create plugin they might replace it with actual content..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by manually typing similar marker what CRM is using. Note that this is not documented in SDK.

[Dynamic Values For Custom Entities In Email Templates](https://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2015/11/dynamic-values-custom-entities-email-templates/)

> In the template, where you want the value to appear, type within 2 brackets an exclamation point followed by the entity logical name. After the entity name, add a colon, and then the field logical name, ending it with a semi colon. If you’d like a default value if nothing was found, after the semi colon add the default value.

```
{!<entitylogicalname>: <fieldlogicalname>; <Default Text>}
```

More in part 2:

> The Global Template Type is what you’d want to use for custom
>   entities, or any other entity not listed in the template type drop
>   down menu. And just to reiterate, regardless of the way you insert
>   values, whether you use the out of the box insert method or you
>   manually type it in, you can only insert values from one record.

[Dynamic Values For Email Templates - Part 2](https://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2017/01/dynamic-values-email-templates-part-2/)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics' email templates are flawed. You either can't use custom entities or you have no translation. I use this workflow instead. It can do everything : https://github.com/rtebar/dynamics-custom-emails